# belongs_to conditions to match a relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have

```
User belongsTo Group
```

And there is also a user whose own the group, so:

```
class Group ...
  belongs_to :owner, -> { 
    joins(:groups).where( 'groups.id = users.group_id') 
  }, class_name: 'User'
```

I would like to limit this relationship to only the users who are already on the group.

However on the `lambda` self is `User`, so I'm not able to access my original object (a `Group`)

That code is not working because it returns all users, not only the ones belonging to that group.

Any idea?

Comment: What defines the owner of the group? You would have to identify that first and I'm not seeing anything about that here. Maybe add a boolean in the table to identify the owner?

Comment: The groups table has a `user_id` field, thats the owner, and the users table has a `group_id` , thats the user it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end


class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, -> { where("users.group_id = id") }, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```